# Remove values from one list based on the IDs removed from another

Tags: r, list

I have a data frame that I have split into a list based on `ID` (`l1`). I also have another list `l2` that is connected to `l1` based on the `ID` names. One of the list elements has a `NA` value, and I have removed that element out of the list (`l2_new`).

I would like to be able to remove the same `ID` value from `l1` that I removed from `l2` due to the `NA` value leading to the `expected` object. Is there a good way to do this (preferably in base R)?

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("01-01-2013"), dmy("31-12-2013"), by = "days"), 300)
ID <-  rep(c("A","B","C"), 50)
df <- data.frame(date = date,
                   utm_x = runif(length(date), min = 238785, max = 453354.5),
                   utm_y = runif(length(date), min = 4096853.0  , max = 4280487.1 ),
                   ID)

l1 <- df %>% 
  group_split(ID)

names(l1) <- sapply(l1, function(x) paste(x$ID[1],
                                            sep = '_'))

l2 <- list(1,2,NA)
names(l2) <- c("A", "B", "C")

l2_new <- Filter(function(a) any(!is.na(a)), l2)

expected <- l2[-3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the names of 'l2_new' to subset the 'l2'

```
l2[names(l2_new)]
```